# How can I optimise a Pandas Dataframe filter operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, indexing

I have a method that iterates over a series of pandas groupBy objects, then filters a second dataframe based on the column values of these objects and assigns the group counts to a column in the second dataframe (this is done using .loc and boolean arrays)

Here is the code:

```
compound_data_frame = {
        'category': {0: 'p1', 1: 'p1', 2: 'p2'},
        'description': {0: 'd1', 1: 'd2', 2: 'd3'},
        'category_order': {0: 'p1', 1: 'p1', 2: 'p2'},
        'position_in_sequence': {0: 'p1', 1: 'p1', 2: 'p2'},
        'categorical_property': {0: 'p1', 1: 'p1', 2: 'p2'},
    }
    compound_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(compound_data_frame)

    results = {
        'category': {0: 'p1', 1: 'p1', 2: 'p2'},
        'description': {0: 'd1', 1: 'd2', 2: 'd3'},
        'unit_type': {0: 'categorical_property', 1: 'categorical_property', 2: 'categorical_property'},
        'unit': {0: 'p1', 1: 'p1', 2: 'p2'}
        'count_start_previous_category_x': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}
    }
    results = pd.DataFrame(results)

counts = compound_data_frame.groupby(
                  ['category', 'description', 'category_order', 'position_in_sequence', 'categorical_property']).size()

for index, count in counts.iteritems():
    category_equality = (results['category'] == index[0])
    description_equality = (results['description'] == index[1])
    unit_type_equality = (results['unit_type'] == 'categorical_property')
    unit_equality = (results['unit'] == index[4])
    column_name = 'count_start_previous_category_x'
    results.loc[category_equality & description_equality & unit_type_equality & unit_equality, column_name] = count
```

This is taking much too long, and I wanted to know whether this is because of the groupby or because of filtering the results dataframe to create the boolean arrays, or the final .loc. I thought about creating a multi-index on the relevant columns in the results dataframe, but I would like to leave its structure as it is. If anyone knows of a way to optimise this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data in order to understand and reproduce more easily ?

Comment: @Alexandre B I've added code for creating the two dataframes with dummy data.